# sorting struct in C cant show output result in VS2017, but show in CodeBlocks

Tags: c, sorting, struct

So basically I want to sort number in file. so i read first

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        fscanf(read_file, "%d %s %d %s\n", &custid_temp[i].id, custid_temp[i].name, &custid_temp[i].reward_point, custid_temp[i].promo);
        printf("%d %s %d %s\n", custid_temp[i].id, custid_temp[i].name, custid_temp[i].reward_point, custid_temp[i].promo);
    }
```

The File consist of this:

```
1 Test 200 WELCOME2017
2 James 700 WELCOME2017
```

See it is the points, 200 and 700 in files, I want to sort in ascending order (largest to smallest) become like this:

```
2 James 700 WELCOME2017
1 Test 200 WELCOME2017
```

So I will sort the file using this function:

```
for (int i = 0; i<count+1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<count - i; j++)
        { 
            if (custid[j].reward_point <custid[j + 1].reward_point)
            {
                struct customer temp_sort = custid[j];
                custid[j] = custid[j + 1];
                custid[j + 1] = temp_sort;
            }
        }
    }
```

And lastly print the updated struct:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%d %s %d %s\n", custid[i].id, custid[i].name, custid[i].reward_point, custid[i].promo);
    }
```

The result is this(VS2017):

```
1 Test 200 WELCOME2017
2 James 700 WELCOME2017
0  0
0  0
```

The result is this(CodeBlocks):

```
1 Test 200 WELCOME2017
2 James 700 WELCOME2017
2 James 700 WELCOME2017
1 Test 200 WELCOME2017

Process returned 2 (0x2)   execution time : 0.015 s
Press any key to continue.
```

How come two compiler produce 2 different result, even with the same code, is there any solution for this to work on VS2017?

Thanks for the time anyway.

Comment: The debugger is your friend.

Comment: `custid[j + 1]` ocuurs out-of-bounds.

Comment: Visual Studio and CodeBlocks are IDEs, not compilers. Visual Studio either uses Microsoft's `cl.exe` or a modified version of Clang. CodeBlocks can support a wide range of compilers AFAIK.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY , but if I change to `custid[j + 1]` to `custid[j]` or `custid[j - 1]`, It produces this.  `1 Test 200 WELCOME2017
2 James 700 WELCOME2017
1 Test 200 WELCOME2017
2 James 700 WELCOME2017

Process returned 2 (0x2)   execution time : 0.010 s
Press any key to continue.`    Which means its not sorted anymore

Comment: You use `custid_temp` as read. But You use `custid` as sort.

Comment: try [this](http://ideone.com/j7icTD)

Comment: Ok I sort it out, maybe my for copying exact data from codeblock, which led to confusion. Sorry guys, Thanks for all of your help, And have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to approach the sorting problem more generally. Define an order by implementing a comparator function to be able to decide, if an element is smaller, equal or greater than another element. Define a function interface, which takes your array and a function pointer to your comparator (taking two elements of your array as parameters and returning -1, 0 or 1 for smaller, equal or greater).

Finally use quicksort or another well-known algorithm to perform the actual sorting. Decide if you require the order to be total - a property which is desirable, if your sorting algorithm is supposed to return deterministic results.

More specifically, I'd encourage the use of `qsort` from the C standard library. It's pretty well documented: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Search_002fSort-Example.html